# SSRS Lookupset sum problem when one or more value are nothing

Tags: reporting-services

I got a little problem with Lookupset on a SSRS Report.
The report has a father-child structure in the group section and the datasets come from different tabular.

The problem occurs when one of the Product from Dataset1 is missing on Dataset2, the entire sum returns 0.
I tried this VB code in order to sum up all the values the Lookupset is able to return.

```
    Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
    If items Is Nothing Then
    Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
    suma = 0
    For Each item As Object In items
    suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
    Next
    Return suma
    End Function
```

I expected the sum of every Product Lookupset is able to retrurn me but it is just returning 0 if one of the Products is missing in Dataset2.

Is there a way to manage the Nothing returned by Lookupset?

Sorry for the formatting and my poor english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by checking for the value in your **LOOKUPSET** expression that SumLookup is summing.

I **ass**u**me** that your expression looks something like this:

```
=CODE.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!ProductID.Value, 
    Fields!ProductID.Value, 
    Fields!Price.value, 
    "Dataset2") )
```

Use an **IIF** with **ISNOTHING** to check for the NULL values and set them to zero:

```
=CODE.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!ProductID.Value, 
    Fields!ProductID.Value, 
    IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Price.value), 0.00, Fields!Price.value), 
    "Dataset2") )
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a `Decimal` datatype. By a `Decimal` datatype `Nothing` and `0` are the same. You can test this.

Put a tablix into your report with year from 2017 to 2019. Then put the year in a column of the tablix as a number format, then write the following expression in the detail textbox:

```
=CDec(IIF(CDec(Fields!Year.Value) = 2017, 0, Nothing))
```

After executing your report you will notice that every value in the year column is `0`.

The same goes for the check. Both of these expressions will always return `Yes`. I basically check for `0` and the second one for for `Nothing`:

```
=IIF(CDec(IIF(CDec(Fields!Jahr.Value) = 2017, 0, Nothing)) = 0, "Yes", "No")
=IIF(CDec(IIF(CDec(Fields!Jahr.Value) = 2017, 0, Nothing)) = Nothing, "Yes", "No")
```

But remember your textbox/column has the be a number format.

So if you want to return `Nothing` and you display it in a number format textbox, it will show you a `0`.